# The meaning of "start on the running-down tack"

Tags: meaning, expressions

> After a few days it occurred to me to go to the office of Mr. J.M.M. Baxter-the solicitor who had sold Holmescroft to M'Leod. I explained I had some notion of buying the place. Would he act for me in the matter?
> Mr. Baxter, a large, greyish, throaty-voiced man, showed no enthusiasm. “I sold it to Mr. M'Leod,” he said. “**It 'ud scarcely do for me to start on the running-down tack now**. But I can recommend-”

This is from "The House Surgeon" by Rudyard Kipling.   
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2381/2381-h/2381-h.htm#link2H_4_0016  
I don't understand the meaning of "It 'ud scarcely do for me to start on the running-down tack now."

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: "It 'ud scarcely do" means "It would not be proper." No idea about "running-down tack."

Comment: Maybe "running down" can mean that as a buyer's agent, he would have to argue that the property wasn't worth as much, that is he'd have to run it down. "Tack" might be from sailing, where one alternates directions to sail against the wind. So, he'd have to switch from building up the property's value to sell it to M'Leod, then switch to running down the value to buy it. That might occasion some embarrassment for the agent.

Comment: "It'ud" is how this character pronounces "It'd", the contraction of "It would".

Answer (score 1):

In the final analysis it's a matter of opinion (the actual text is in principle "ambiguous"), but I'm pretty sure "running-down tack" here is a quirky / colloquial "nonce-noun" formation deriving from...

> ***[to run down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/run-down) = to criticize / find fault with***
> (combined with ***tack = direction / approach / course of action***).

The speaker ***doesn't want to be openly critical about Mr M'Leod*** (to whom he sold the house), but it seems pretty obvious he doesn't think very highly of him. So the speaker is initially "diffident" about taking on the job of trying to buy the house *back*, but within a couple of paragraphs it's obvious he's agreed to do this.

---

[Here's another instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22going%20on%20the%20running%20down%20tack%22%22) of the exact text under consideration, where my interpretation obvious applies...

> *He's such an ugly man," said Miss Agnes, going on **the running-down tack** also*

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22running%20down%20tack%22) are several *more* written instances of ***the running-down tack*** from Google Books, so obviously the collocation isn't *quite* the "one-off nonce term" I originally thought when I started writing this answer. I'm now quite certain those Google Books matches will all have essentially the same meaning - but the "Miss Agnes" one above is probably the best for making that meaning contextually obvious.

---

As pointed out by [@randomhead](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/289344/the-meaning-of-start-on-the-running-down-tack/289366#comment539076_289344) in a comment, *It 'ud scarcely do* means *It would not be proper*.

Answer (score 0):

It means that he doesn't feel it would now be worth his time to try to find the person.

In this case, "tack" means a course of action,

"running-down", means to track or find something

Comment: Initially a plausible interpretation, but not once I looked more closely into things. It's ***running down = slagging off / criticizing***

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a metaphor from sailing. In sailing, you can "tack" to sail into the wind. Or you can "run" to go with the wind.

And so "start on the running down tack" suggests "going back and undoing the work one has already done".